Why is the only off-topic option CS.meta?
In voting to close, why is the only off-topic option the CS.meta?  That forces "off-topic" to mean the much more specific and less useful "on-topic in meta"!

Before getting to the option of CS.meta, you first encounter a custom close reason 'self-help' and 'other'. Only when choosing it belongs on another site CS.meta is listed, along with the option to provide your own. Don't know whether we can add other defaults, but if, which ones would you suggest?

Why should there be a limited set of defaults?  For example, there's a question on the CS main page right now that should be migrated to chem.SE--but I can't put that in the off-topic vote.  Is there another way to point out a question which should be migrated, and where it might be migrated to? (Besides leaving a comment, of course.  I've done that, and the questioner doesn't seem to notice that biochem and cognitive are not the same domain.)

Hmm, possibly only mods can specify other sites in the close reason. I only see this box on CogSci, not on Stack Overflow. I am interested to follow up on the specific question. My first impression is indeed that it would be better of on chemistry, but I'll give it some time.

@StevenJeuris: I think the method might be to write a feature request here on meta, and maybe poke any SE employees you have access to. I've been thinking we should have a couple more sites on the migration short list for a while too, but I'm not sure which, and we're limited to 5. Here are a few prime candidates, judging from the list of migrations in the mod tools (won't be visible below 2000 rep AFAIK):

Biology: three migrated since mid-January
Personal Productivity: three migrated
Cross Validated: two
Philosophy: one
Skeptics: one
Linguistics: one

There were also two migrated to Academia, and one each to Stack Overflow, Open Data, and Movies & TV, but I don't see a substantive link with any of these.
I would prefer to keep Meta.CogSci on the list, and add the top two or three for starters.

As far as I remember, beta sites are not allowed as default migration targets.

OIC...that would just leave Cross Validated and Skeptics. :\  Maybe Academia would make more sense to add too in that case, at least until one of these more closely related sites graduates?
